# General two state system with general pertubation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory, two-level-system

I am trying to solve this two-level system with time independent perturbation problem

> Consider an atomic system with only two stationary states $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ , of respective energies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ . Suppose that $\omega_1 < \omega_2$ and that the system is initially in its ground state. At time t = 0, a time-independent perturbation W is switched on. By solving the Schroedinger equation with perturbation, calculate the probability to find the system in either of the two states at time t as a function of the frequencies $\omega_1 , \omega_2$ and the coefficients $W_{ij} = \langle i | W | j \rangle $.

I would say this is easily solved by applying first order time dependent perturbation theory i.e. calculating: $|\langle n|U_I|1\rangle |^2$ to get both probabilities.

I have a solution here that goes a different way though and gets a different solution. They can not both be right? Why is this ansatz wrong?

Comment: In this case with a finite number of levels the system remains oscillating between the states and this is not covered by first order perturbation theory.

Comment: Making this ansatz for the Wave function: $|\Psi \rangle = e^{{i \over \hbar} H_0 t}( |\Psi^{(0)} \rangle +\lambda |\Psi^{(1)} \rangle )$ where these are just $ |\Psi^{(0)} \rangle = c_1^{(0)}|1\rangle +c_2^{(0)}|2\rangle$ and $ |\Psi^{(1)} \rangle = c_1^{(1)}|1\rangle +c_2^{(1)}|2\rangle$ and putting it through the time dependent Schrödinger equation you get a solution. This is one version of  first order time dependent pertubation theory. I suspect the difference is in that you actually get states here and normalize them, but the Probabilitties should not be affected by that should they?